# Oracle Eloqua syncedInstanceUri error

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I developed a `Feeder Service` for Eloqua and whenever the syncronization happens I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: {
>   "failures":[{"field":"syncedInstanceUri","detail":"Must reference
>   CloudFeeder instance within a WorkFlow"}]}
>
> ```
>     at com.on24.common.ejb.service.wcc.eloqua.client.contact.EloquaContactClient.importData(EloquaContactClient.java:100)
>     at com.on24.common.ejb.service.wcc.eloqua.client.contact.EloquaContactSync.run(EloquaContactSync.java:135)
>     at com.on24.common.ejb.service.wcc.eloqua.client.asyncQueue.EloquaSyncProcess.process(EloquaSyncProcess.java:216)
>     at com.on24.common.ejb.service.wcc.eloqua.client.asyncQueue.EloquaSyncProcess.run(EloquaSyncProcess.java:114)
>     at com.on24.common.handler.EloquaSyncHandler.process(EloquaSyncHandler.java:16)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> ```

I've searched everywhere but eloqua documentation doesn't have much help when it comes to error messages, so does anyone know exactly what this response from eloqua mean:

> { "failures":[{"field":"syncedInstanceUri","detail":"Must reference
>   CloudFeeder instance within a WorkFlow"}]}

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are trying to import data into a feeder in a campaign or a program and the failure occurs when you synchronize the data for import.

When you create the bulk import definition set the "destination" field to the AppCloud Feeders service's instance (without dashes) - in this example, the instance ID is 9347bfe1-9c72-409c-a5cd-402ff74f0caa:

```
"syncActions": [
    {
      "destination": "{{FeederInstance(9347bfe19c72409ca5cd402ff74f0caa)}}",
      "action": "setStatus",
      "status": "complete"
    }
  ]
```

Make sure the instance id is correct and it exists in an active campaign or program.

Here is the doc for the feeder service and a sample import: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/AppCloud/Develop/develop-feeder-service.htm

Comment: Yes, I already checked the syncActions and it is all ok, so this isn't the problem

Comment: Can you post an example of all the calls? It will be easier to help with more data.